# jQuery: Modifying A tags within a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add `target="_blank"` to some "A" tags within a textarea. I am able to modify them when they are not inside a textarea but I cannot do it when they are inside the textarea.

For this code I only want to add the target attributes when it is an external link. [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/46n3jhz7/)

```
<form>
<textarea id="description">
<a href="https://www.website.com/">internal</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">external no target</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">external target</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">external no target</a>
<a href="https://website.com/">internal</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">external no target</a>
</textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success">Go</button>

</form>

<a href="https://www.google.com/">external no target</a>
```

I have tried a few different ways of specifying that the links are within a textarea but none work. Here is one version I have tried...

```
// This does not work...
$('#description a:not([target])').not('a[href*=website]').attr('target', '_blank');

// This works for the link 
$('a:not([target])').not('a[href*=website]').attr('target', '_blank');
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When they're in a text area they're a string, not DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are text and not actual elements you need to manipulate the string.

A simple way is to put the string into a temporary element as html , run dom methods on that element and return the updated html

Something like:

```
$('#description').val(function(_,currVal){
    var $div = $('<div>').append(currVal);
     $div.find('a:not([target])').not('a[href*=website]').attr('target', '_blank');
    return $div.html()
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything you put inside a `<textarea>` tag becomes its value in plain text.
That means they are no longer HTML elements and thus cannot be selected with jQuery.

Textareas are used for user input, and the only reason to put anything inside them is as a default value.
Why do you want to have links inside it?